# Show the Application in Task manager

Tags: c#

When ever run my installed solution the application name differ from my application. How can i show the application name in Task manager use visual studio 2013

Comment: This is easy to do. Task Manager reads it from the file version resource, an unmanaged resource embedded into a program. The equivalent in .NET is the FileVersionInfo.FileDescription property.

Easiest way to set it is with Project + Properties, Compile tab, Assembly Information button, Title field.

Comment: @gPeart This sounds to me like the answer he wants ... why don't you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to do. Task Manager reads it from the file version resource, an unmanaged resource embedded into a program. The equivalent in .NET is the FileVersionInfo.FileDescription property.

The easiest way to set it is with Project + Properties, Compile tab, Assembly Information button, Title field.